# How to derive solution to loss function of GLasso for precision matrix

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-normal-distribution, precision-matrix

I am trying to find the parameter $\hat\omega = min_{\omega}\Big(-log|\omega| + tr(S\omega) + \sum_{i,j}\lambda|\omega_{ij}|\Big)$

This is to regularize the precision matrix $\omega$ for the GLasso.  I have been studying the Lasso for regression and that makes sense, but I have no idea and cannot find how to find $\hat\omega$ given an initial empirical covariance matrix S for centered MVN .

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated. [paper is here I am reading, EQ(5).](https://opt-ml.org/papers/2021/paper2.pdf)
I am trying to code this paper to work for something I want to try in assembling predictions from multiple machine learning models.